# C# Form2 chamando o Form1

Tags: c#

Boa noite estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de cadastros de produtos, porém preciso chamar o form2 primeiro do que o form1. Vocês poderiam me auxiliar de como fazer isso?

Comment: Quer que o Form2 apareça ao iniciar a aplicação, ao invés de Form1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vá no arquivo `Program.cs` e lá achará a seguinte linha

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Mude para o formulário que quer utilizar. Em seu caso:

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado deu certo.